# How to set autocomplete for react native elements input on iOS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-native-elements

I am trying to set correct autocomplete suggestions on my registration form.
I am using react native elements input, I have set username, email and password field.
On email field I have set

```
textContentType={'emailAddress'}
keyboardType={'email-address'}
autoCompleteType={'email'}
```

and even so the keyboard is offering me only passwords for autocomplete.
But even weirder is that if I add another input the email autocomplete works fine.
Does anyone know is there anything I should be focusing on?

EDIT1:
Later, with testing I found out, that the keyboard says that it is offering password, but if pressed it fill all the fields

Answer (score 0):

You might try the [`autoCapitalize` field](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#autocapitalize), I found that when I set `autoCompleteType="username"` or `autoCompleteType="password"` I was still getting an uppercase first letter on Android.